# I have a problem with Blender, it bakes the textures to different images

Tags: texture-baking

[image]
I have 6 materials each have an image because my model have different textures and i solved it with material image texture. But Blender bakes the textures into different images. Because in the UV editor there are 6 images.

The UV map is on every image but i want it to be only on the Untitled.001
[image]

Each of them have this node

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Just to clarify, you have a model with 6 materials, each with a unique texture, and you want to bake them into a single texture? Any chance you can edit your question and add an image of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Based on what i can see, there are 6 images available in Blender, but the one that is supposed to be baked on, is black, means most likely the backing did not succeed yet. The dds files are most certainly not baked by Blender.

Comment: I solved it with asign uv map in nodes for the untitled 001 node

Comment: Btw thak you very mutch!